# How to get which object from the collection is used as particle instance in the particle system via bpy?

Tags: python, particles

If particle system uses Collection as particles in the Render tab of the Particle System settings is there a way to get exact object which each particle is assigned to via bpy? I know that other particles attributes can be obtained with the depsgraph, e.g.:

```
import bpy

emitter = bpy.context.object  # assuming it is a particle emitter
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eval_emitter = emitter.evaluated_get(dg)
for ps in eval_emitter.particle_systems:
    for p in ps.particles:
        print(p.location)
```

But I can not find anything related to which object is assigned to particular particle among the particle attributes. Is there a way to get this info directly from the particles or maybe to somehow reproduce exact random distribution of which object is used as an instance for which particle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script lists the evaluated instances, which correspond to a particle system, giving the ps name, original object name and particle location.

```
import bpy

dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

for o in dg.object_instances:
    if o.particle_system:
        print(o.particle_system.name, \
            o.instance_object.name, \
            o.matrix_world.translation)
```

Output

```
ParticleSystem Sphere <Vector (-0.1024, -0.4825, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (-0.4588, 0.2148, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (-0.2058, -0.0513, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (-0.8368, 0.3390, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (0.5467, 0.7251, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (-0.0770, -0.9534, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Sphere <Vector (0.8253, -0.9243, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (0.5836, -0.0743, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Cube <Vector (0.2153, 0.2062, 0.0000)>
ParticleSystem Sphere <Vector (-0.4823, -0.7403, 0.0000)>
```

Comment: Thank you! Taking object instances and their settings directly from the depsgraph seems to be even more useful than iterating through particle systems!